# Could not find OpenSSL ... missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY

Tags: amazon-s3, cmake, openssl, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile the aws-sdk-cpp and I am getting the following error just the very first time I run CMAKE. If I run it a second time it compiles and links and I have tested the application and I can indeed use the aws-sdk-cpp functionality. I have searched and searched for days and tried all kinds of things:

- Setting environment variable for OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR
- Setting it in a cmake variable, etc.

I print the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` variable right before the call to

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

and it prints the right PATH.

I have also set the variable `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to TRUE without any difference.
I honestly don't understand what is going on since if I run it a second time it builds and links just fine.

```
CMake Error at /snap/cmake/1035/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "1.1.1n")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/cmake/1035/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /snap/cmake/1035/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:574 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  Projects/libraries/aws/s3/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-cal/CMakeLists.txt:89 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have figured what was going on.

the issue was that I was setting the values for

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY
```

Once I deleted them it worked.